# Python: Context manager 'generator' doesn't implement __enter__ and __exit__

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, visual-studio-code

I create a sipmple NN model by tensorflow and use VScode as my IDE
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)


class SimpleLogisticClassification:

    def __init__(self, n_features, n_labels, learning_rate=0.5):
        self.n_features = n_features
        self.n_labels = n_labels

        self.weights = None
        self.biases = None

        self.graph = tf.Graph()  # initialize new graph
        self.build(learning_rate)  # building graph
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)  # create session by the graph

    def build(self, learning_rate):
        # Building Graph
        with self.graph.as_default():
            ### Input
            self.train_features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, self.n_features))
            self.train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, self.n_labels))

            ### Optimalization
            # build neurel network structure and get their predictions and loss
            self.y_, self.loss = self.structure(features=self.train_features,
                                                labels=self.train_labels)
            # define training operation
            self.train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)

            ### Prediction
            self.new_features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, self.n_features))
            self.new_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, self.n_labels))
            self.new_y_, self.new_loss = self.structure(features=self.new_features,
                                                        labels=self.new_labels)

            ### Initialization
            self.init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    def structure(self, features, labels):
        # build neurel network structure and return their predictions and loss
        ### Variable
        if (not self.weights) or (not self.biases):
            self.weights = {
                'fc1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(self.n_features, self.n_labels))),
            }
            self.biases = {
                'fc1': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(self.n_labels))),
            }

        ### Structure
        # one fully connected layer
        logits = self.get_dense_layer(features, self.weights['fc1'], self.biases['fc1'])

        # predictions
        y_ = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

        # loss: softmax cross entropy
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                 tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits))

        return (y_, loss)

    def get_dense_layer(self, input_layer, weight, bias, activation=None):
        # fully connected layer
        x = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_layer, weight), bias)
        if activation:
            x = activation(x)
        return x

    def fit(self, X, y, epochs=10, validation_data=None, test_data=None):
        X = self._check_array(X)
        y = self._check_array(y)

        self.sess.run(self.init_op)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            print('Epoch %2d/%2d: ' % (epoch+1, epochs))

            # fully gradient descent
            feed_dict = {self.train_features: X, self.train_labels: y}
            self.sess.run(self.train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)

            # evaluate at the end of this epoch
            y_ = self.predict(X)
            train_loss = self.evaluate(X, y)
            train_acc = self.accuracy(y_, y)
            msg = ' loss = %8.4f, acc = %3.2f%%' % (train_loss, train_acc*100)

            if validation_data:
                val_loss = self.evaluate(validation_data[0], validation_data[1])
                val_acc = self.accuracy(self.predict(validation_data[0]), validation_data[1])
                msg += ', val_loss = %8.4f, val_acc = %3.2f%%' % (val_loss, val_acc*100)

            print(msg)

        if test_data:
            test_acc = self.accuracy(self.predict(test_data[0]), test_data[1])
            print('test_acc = %3.2f%%' % (test_acc*100))

    def accuracy(self, predictions, labels):
        return (np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))/predictions.shape[0])

    def predict(self, X):
        X = self._check_array(X)
        return self.sess.run(self.new_y_, feed_dict={self.new_features: X})

    def evaluate(self, X, y):
        X = self._check_array(X)
        y = self._check_array(y)
        return self.sess.run(self.new_loss, feed_dict={self.new_features: X, self.new_labels: y})

    def _check_array(self, ndarray):
        ndarray = np.array(ndarray)
        if len(ndarray.shape) == 1:
            ndarray = np.reshape(ndarray, (1, ndarray.shape[0]))
        return ndarray


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Extract MNIST Dataset ...')

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)

    train_data = mnist.train
    valid_data = mnist.validation
    test_data = mnist.test

    model = SimpleLogisticClassification(n_features=28*28,
                                         n_labels=10,
                                         learning_rate=0.5)
    model.fit(X=train_data.images,
              y=train_data.labels,
              epochs=10,
              validation_data=(valid_data.images, valid_data.labels),
              test_data=(test_data.images, test_data.labels), )
```

But when I run, I got the error below:

> Context manager 'generator' doesn't implement **enter** and **exit**.

It seem like something wrong to my with statement，I got error from my default graph.
But I can run the code from other IDE, I still want to know how to fix it.
Does somebody have idea?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Something is trying to use an object as a context manager when in fact the object isn't one (context managers require `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` to be defined). You will probably have to read the documentation to see which object you are passing in is supposed to be a context manager or provide more error details.

Comment: A full stacktrace would be useful here in order to get an answer, most people will not dig through the documentation to figure out what's wrong.